# php - map table row with a href link dynamically

Tags: php, arrays, href

I have an array which i use to dynamically create a table.
I have a name=value pair (Server=server.alias) which values are being extracted and would like to make it **hyperlinked** to another webpage.

What I need help is figuring out the code to map the alias name with a specific href link which I think I will have to hard code. The href link is **different** for each alias, so there is no pattern there.

Would an if statement be appropriate for this? Any other suggestions to do this? Thank you.

Expected Output:

```
Server  
----------------
server1.alias  <-- hreflink = http://server1.name.com:/9999
server2.alias  <-- hreflink = http://server2.name.colo.com:/2999
```

My code so far generating the dynamic rows look like this:

```
$keys = array('Server');                                                              
echo '<table><tr>';                             
foreach ($keys as $column)
   echo '<th>' . $column . '</th>';
    echo '</tr>';

foreach ($data as $row){
   echo '<tr>';                                         
     foreach ($keys as $column)                 
        if (isset($row[$column])){                                                                   
          echo '<td>' . $row[$column];
          } else {
          echo '<td>' . '' . '</td>';
        }
}
echo '</table>';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the key to solving your problem is that you will need more information to be able to create the list that you want with a foreach. My suggestion would be to use something like this :

```
$server_array = array(
  'server1' => array(
    'alias' => 'server1.alias',
    'href' => 'http//server1.name.com'
  ),
  'server2' => array(
    'alias' => 'server2.alias',
    'href' => 'http//server2.name.colo.com'
  )
);
```

You definitely need all info in your array, otherwise, you'll never be able to do what you want.

EDIT:

With the above array, the foreach loop would be like this :

```
foreach($server_array as $server_id => $server_info)
{
  echo 'Server ID: '.$server_id;
  echo 'Server Alias: '.$server_info['alias'];
  echo 'Server URL: '.$server_info['href'];
}
```

The formatting code is missing, but you get the idea.

Comment: so essentially, $server_array will feed into the foreach loop? so basically do a compare of the name=value as a key to the href? thanks.

Comment: I edited my answer to add an example of the foreach that you would need to print everything. Let me know if it helps.